# Filtering out options with identical text strings

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, list, list-view, filter

One of my SharePoint lists contains a choice column the allows for multiple selections (i.e., a checkbox list.) It's used to identify legislation relevant to the list item, and often multiple pieces of legislation will need to be selected.

I want to create views for each of the individual choices in this column, to easily pull up views that show each item tagged with a given with a piece of legislation. However, some pieces of legislation contain identical text strings, and any filter I attempt to build retrieves all the options with that text string.

To give a concrete example: I want to build a view that only shows items tagged with *Municipalities Act.* So I went in and set the view filter to "[contains] Municipalities Act."
However, that exact text string is duplicated in *Northern Municipalities Act,* so the latter shows up in my view as well.

Because SharePoint's filtering options don't provide a "does not contain" option, I can't figure out how to filter out options with overlapping text strings. I tried adding a space between the word "Municipality" and the word "Act" to differentiate the two strings, but that didn't seem to have any effect.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use `is equal to` operator instead of `contains` operator in list view filter settings.

**For example**:

List view filter settings are like:

[image]

**Output**:

It shows the list items with "A" selected in multiple selection choice column named "Scope":

[image]